# Increase in not found error - WordPress SEO by Yoast

Tags: php, wordpress, seo

I get this message from webmaster tools :

> Google detected a significant increase in the number of URLs that
>   return a 404 (Page Not Found) error. Investigating these errors and
>   fixing them where appropriate ensures that Google can successfully
>   crawl your site's pages.

My CMS is wordpress .
I used `SEO by Yoast`, I deactivated it and install `All In One SEO Pack` and `Google XML Sitemaps` plugins.
after three days I get over 2000 not found page link from webmaster tools .

[image]

Comment: And what happens if you disable those?

Comment: Are these urls which you want indexed ? If not, then 404 is the correct response.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not about computer programming.

Answer (score 1):

Hey Bro do not worry about this. Please block this url from Google crawling list. 
These urls are looking like its date archive. You can block this via Robots.txt file or in plugin setting.

After that with in 1 week these not found errors will decreasing.

Vote if Helpful

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like your XML sitemaps plugin is generating a lot of false URLs and submitting them to Google for indexing. Could you disable it, and upload a manual sitemap instead?

You might also need to go back into Webmaster Tools and remove all those incorrect URLs and see if there's any page other than your sitemap on your site (or on an external site) that's linking to these incorrect page URLs